# API request not working with rest-client but working with Faraday/cURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client, faraday

I have an GET request to query JOOR API to retrieve their product category list.

This request works fine with cURL or Faraday gem, but not working well with rest-client gem. The testing request results are below:

1) With cURL

```
curl -X GET \
  https://apisandbox.jooraccess.com/v2/categories/ \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [mytoken]' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

2) With faraday

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: 'https://apisandbox.jooraccess.com/v2/categories')
conn.get do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.headers['Authorization'] = 'Oauth2 [mytoken]'
end
```

3) With rest-client

```
response = ::RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'https://apisandbox.jooraccess.com/v2/categories', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Oauth2 [mytoken]'})
```

1) and 2) both get expected response with a list of categories, but 3) got response with a complaint saying 'Request/Response format is not supported'

So what's the difference between 3) and 1)/2)? Why does only 3) fail?

========== UPDATE ==========

Used httplog gem to log the header info for both Faraday and Rest-client requests. Here's the log.

Faraday:

```
[httplog] Connecting: apisandbox.jooraccess.com:443
[httplog] Sending: GET http://apisandbox.jooraccess.com:443/v2/categories
[httplog] Header: user-agent: Faraday v0.9.2
[httplog] Header: content-type: application/json
[httplog] Header: authorization: Oauth2 [mytoken]
[httplog] Header: accept-encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
[httplog] Header: accept: */*
[httplog] Header: connection: close
[httplog] Data:
[httplog] Status: 200
[httplog] Benchmark: 0.2766950000077486 seconds
[httplog] Header: content-type: application/json
[httplog] Header: date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 05:56:16 GMT
[httplog] Header: server: nginx
[httplog] Header: server-time: 2018-06-08T05:56:16+00:00+00:00
[httplog] Header: vary: Cookie
[httplog] Header: content-length: 6958
[httplog] Header: connection: Close
[httplog] Response:
{
    "categories_list": {
        "response": {
            "code": "0",
            "comment": "",
...
```

Rest-Client:

```
[httplog] Connecting: apisandbox.jooraccess.com:443
[httplog] Sending: GET http://apisandbox.jooraccess.com:443/v2/categories
[httplog] Header: accept: */*; q=0.5, application/xml
[httplog] Header: accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
[httplog] Header: content-type: application/json
[httplog] Header: authorization: Oauth2 [mytoken]
[httplog] Header: user-agent: Ruby
[httplog] Data:
[httplog] Status: 200
[httplog] Benchmark: 0.25124399999913294 seconds
[httplog] Header: content-type: application/xml
[httplog] Header: date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 06:05:31 GMT
[httplog] Header: server: nginx
[httplog] Header: server-time: 2018-06-08T06:05:31+00:00+00:00
[httplog] Header: vary: Cookie
[httplog] Header: content-length: 202
[httplog] Header: connection: keep-alive
[httplog] Response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <code>8</code>
    <comment>Request/Response format is not supported</comment>
    <log_id>9950b3b7-0e92-4514-9d2b-29d4b006fdc8</log_id>
</response>
```

It shows that Content-Type in header probably didn't pass in correctly after processing by rest-client. So the way I use rest-client may be incorrect. How shall I correct it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the syntax, do you have a sample token for test account that I could try

Comment: @Subash What I can confirm is no 401 issues for all calls. Just found something may help, will update question in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this to your rest-client code

```
response = ::RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'https://apisandbox.jooraccess.com/v2/categories', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Oauth2 [mytoken]'})
```

Comment: This works too. It seems rest-client tends to set some default accept value for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add `accept: '*/*'` in the header for rest-client request. And it works.

Comment: its better to specify the format of the data that you accept instead of accepting anything with */*